# Using ArcPy to check for duplicates AND Latest date?

Tags: arcpy, select, dictionary

I am stumped (and new to Python). 
I have a feature class with a field that contains a centroid in MGRS. That field is called MGRS.
I also have another field called ED_Date that is the production date of a map.

The MGRS field has many coincidental points because there may be several maps over the same area, but produced at different dates.

I need to look for duplicate MGRS attributes, then FROM those, get the latest one into a selection. After this iterates through the entire table, export those selected features into a new class or maybe append them. I have not decided yet.

Below is an example of my table:

[image]

I have thought about trying to do a dictionary of the MGRS field and then selecting the dates.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments there are other ways of doing this. But you are correct that a Dictionary can be used. Execute in Python window of ArcMap or if standalone you need to create the feature layer using MakeFeatureLayer. If you dont want to use the actual geometries (SHAPE@XY) you can replace this with the name of your field (MGRS)

```
import arcpy

feature_layer = 'Points' #Change
datefield = 'Date' #Change

#List all values:
all_values = [list(i) for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_layer,['SHAPE@XY',datefield,'OID@'])]
#Sort by date:
all_values_sorted = sorted(all_values, key=lambda x: (x[1]))
#Create dictionary. OID of point with most recent date overwrite others when duplicate key (duplicate SHAPE@XY) are found:
d = {j[0]:j[2] for j in all_values_sorted}
#Use OIDS from dictionary values to select:
sql = """{0} IN({1})""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(feature_layer, arcpy.Describe(feature_layer).OIDFieldname), ','.join(str(v) for v in list(d.values())))

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=feature_layer,
                                        where_clause=sql)
```

[image]